# Google Sheets / Excel : Opportunity cost from a set of cash outflows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets, finance

Suppose I have a set of cash outflows at the end of each year. I want to compute the cumulative opportunity cost of the cash outflows each year.

[image: spreadsheet]
In the example above, suppose investments return 4% per year.

At the end of year 1 I pay out $100.

At the end of year 2 I pay out an additional $200. The opportunity cost so far is the return I *would have* made if I had kept $100 in investments for year 2.

At the end of year 3 I pay out an additional $300. The opportunity cost so far is the return I *would have* made if I had not paid $100 in year 1 and not paid $200 in year 2.

Is there some way I can express this in a formula that can be autofilled in Google Sheets?

Context: I'm building a calculator to look at the relative costs of buying vs renting a home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In excel you can use following formula starting at `C7`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$5:B5)*(((1+$B$2)^ABS($B$4:B4-MAX($B$4:B4)-1))-1))
```

[image]